# How to populate the table dynamically and correctly with Ajax?

Tags: ajax, xml, dynamic, html-table

I have a form where the user submits a query and then have a Servlet that processes this query and returns the results in XML. With this result trying to populate a table dynamically via Ajax, for such, I use the following code below.

```
var thead = $("<thead>");
var rowsTHead = $("<tr>");
var tbody = $("<tbody>");
var numberOfColumns;

$(xml).find("head").each(function(){
  var variable = $(this).find("variable");
   numberOfColumns = variable.length;
   for (var i = 0; i < variable.length; i++){
     var name = $(variable[i]).attr("name");
     rowsTHead.append($("<th>").html(name));
   }
});
thead.append(rowsTHead);

$(xml).find("result").each(function(){
   var literal = $(this).find("literal");
   var rowsTBody = $("<tr class=\"even\">");

   literal.length = numberOfColumns;
   for (var j = 0; j < literal.length; j++){
      var tdBody = $("<td>");
      tdBody.html($(literal[j]).text());
      rowsTBody.append(tdBody);
   }
   tbody.append(rowsTBody);
});

$(".tablesorter").empty()
 .append(thead)
 .append(tbody);
```

This code works perfectly until it was used in a UNION query. When using a UNION the returned xml comes in the following way http://pastebin.com/y7hXK1Zy

As can be observed, this query has 4 variables that are: gn1, indication1, gn2, indication2.
What is going wrong is that the values of all the variables being written in columns corresponding to gn1 and indication1.

What I wish I was to write the value of each variable in its corresponding column. I wonder what should I change in my code to make this possible.

Answer (score 0):

You need to respect the name values of the binding elements, and relate them back to the columns that you correctly built from parsing the element.  When you are doing the find "literal", you are skipping the parsing of the binding elements.  You should find "binding", respect the name and look up which column to use based on that, and then for each of those, find the "literal" elements for the actual values.

Comment: Hello Chris Morley, thanks for the feedback.
This is the problem, has hit enough head looking for a way to associate the value of the binding to the column and unfortunately can't do this yet.

Could you give me a hint on how to do this check?
Thank you

Comment: Break up the problem. Make sure that you store the columns first.  Make sure that if you had a simple string like "gn1", that you could lookup the column index.  This should be a simple check against your array.  Then, make sure that given a column index as a number, you could write the appropriate empty td elements to get the end result that you are looking for.  Then link it together.

Comment: Hello Chris Morley, good afternoon.

Unable to solve my problem with your tips.

My code is as follows http://pastebin.com/KV4ShRDn

Thanks for the help.

Until the next.